# backbone.js fetch throwing 500 error on .asmx service

Tags: javascript, web-services, backbone.js, asmx

The issue I am having appears to be with the way Backbone.js creates the query string.

Backbone creates the query string like so:

```
Stats.asmx/GetTarget?domainId=-1&timePeriod=M
```

This causes the the asmx service to throw a 500 error.

If I change the query string to:

```
Stats.asmx/GetTarget?domainId="-1"&timePeriod="M"
```

It works as expected. This is the code I am using which produces the 500 error due to not having quotes around the query string params:

```
var params = {
            domainId: "-1",
            timePeriod: "M"
    };
    var targetData = new Targets();
    targetData.fetch({
        data: params,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

I know I can write a custom function to format the query string the way I want but is there a way to add the "" in the query string with Backbone.js?

**EDIT:**

This is what I mean by write a custom function.

In the collection add:

```
domainId: "",    
timePeriod: "",
urlRoot: "Stats.asmx/GetTarget",
url: function() {
    return this.urlRoot + "?" + "domainId=\"" + this.domainId + "\"" + "&"
        + "timePeriod=\"" + this.timePeriod + "\"";
},
```

Then:

```
var targetData = new Targets();
targetData.domainId = "-1";
targetData.timePeriod = "M";
targetData.fetch({
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

But I am sure there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to modify url because I think your parameter will change. Please try to use **[$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)**:

```
targetData.fetch({
    data: $.param(params), // <-- here is the change
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

This is what $.param does:

```
> $.param({page:1,filter:2})
"page=1&filter=2"
```